# If $\lim_{t\to\infty}\varphi(t)=x_0$, does this imply that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\varphi'(t)=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} \phi(t) = X_0$, where $X_0$ is a constant in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\lim_{t\to \infty} \phi'(t) = 0$.

I search everywhere and I need to know if this is true.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not true, in general.

Take for example
$$
f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-x}\sin(\mathrm{e}^{2x})
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0,
$$
while $f'(x)=-\mathrm{e}^{-x}\sin(\mathrm{e}^{2x})+\mathrm{e}^{x}\cos(\mathrm{e}^{2x})$,
and clearly the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ DOES NOT exist.

Nevertheless, if both $\,\,\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\,\,$ and $\,\,\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)\,\,$ exist, then indeed
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0.$$